# Convert formatted date to html date format

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to convert this date format
`2019-11-27T00:00:00` to the html date format of `2019-11-27`. Is there an existing function on moment which does this?

Comment: `moment("2019-11-27T00:00:00").format("YYYY-MM-DD");`

Comment: And how can I convert ```2019-11-27``` back to the formatted date out of curiousity? So hoping to get ```2019-11-27T00:00:00```

Comment: `new Date("2019-11-27").toISOString()`

Comment: @Layhout—please post answers as answers, not comments. That way others can comment on the answer effectively. It doesn't make sense to convert a string to a date and back to a string when a simple string operation will do the job much more efficiently (and without the need for a large library).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do this natively with the following code:

```js
const dateRaw = "2019-11-27T00:00:00"
const dateFormatted = dateRaw.split("T")[0] // -> 2019-11-27
```